# Is inclusion map not the same as identity?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Wikipedia says $i$ is an inclusion means $i: A \to B$ with $A \subset B$ means $i(x) = x$ for each $x\in A$.

But doesn't this mean $i(A) = A$, so this is actually identity?

Comment: To be the identity map it is necessary $A=B.$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No it isn't the identity since it isn't surjective. In the case when $B=A$ then this injection is the identity.

Comment: But it is surjective with $A$.

Comment: What do you mean by surjective with $A$?

Comment: I mean $i(A) = A$.

Comment: $i$ is surjective if $\forall b\in B$ there's $a\in A$ such that $i(a)=b$. Now take $b\in B-A$ to see that $i$ isn't surjective if $B\ne A$.

Comment: Okay I understand that it isn't the identity on $B$, but it is identity on $A$ right?

Comment: If you mean by "it's the identity on $A$" that the map $i: A\to i(A),\; x\mapsto x$ is the identity then it's right.

Answer (score 11):

Recall the definition: Two functions are equal if **they have the same domain, codomain** and if for each $x$ in the domain they take the same value...

You are missing the bolded part.

Comment: I thought that two functions are equal if they are the same set of ordered pairs.

Comment: @Asaf: While that definition has some merit, if you don't include the codomain as part of the definition, you can't speak of surjectivity as an intrinsic property of the function. (You can, of course, still speak of a function being "surjective over the set $B$".)

Comment: @Ilmari: Strange how set theorists talk about surjections all the time!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Correct me if I am wrong, but I thought that the formal definition of a function is a SUBset of ordered pairs, the subset being in the product of domain and co-domain.

Comment: The two most common definitions are (1) a set of ordered pairs with some property, (2) an ordered triplet consisting of a set of ordered pairs, domain and codomain. In the first definition the domain can be extracted from the ordered pairs, but the codomain cannot, whereas in the second definition changing the codomain will change the function. Both definitions are useful, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is far from my area of expertise, but the usual definition of function I meet is a function is a subset of $A \times B$ with certain properties....But I can see that you can define the concept of ordered pair without defining it as a subset of a cartesian product, and then the co-domain is not part of the definition... But almost all the books I saw have the codomain as part of the definition of the function...And the big question for me, as somebody who is not used with both definitions, is the following: how do you differentiate between an embedding of object A in Object B

Comment: and the isomorphism between object A and the subobject C of B isomorphic to A? By object here I am thinking about algebraic objects: group, ring, field,...

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question, but the analogy is like Intel and AMD, how can you tell from the outside which processor the computer has? You can't, since both run the same architecture. Function is an abstract concept, we can realize it in several ways, but in most cases we don't make any appeals to one realization that we can't somehow make with the other. There is no notion of isomorphism here, we don't need one.

Answer (score 2):

Map *i* is not identity map,to be identity codomain and domain has to be same.

Also, we can say map **i** is identity on **A**.

Answer (score 1):

Two maps $f,g$ are the same if their domain is the same and $f(x)=g(x) \hspace{0.5cm}\forall \hspace{0.2cm}x \in D=D(f)=D(g)$. In your case the first condition is not satisfied.

Comment: In the most common definition, the codomains are also required to be the same. In the original example, the functions have the same domain *A*, but different codomains (*A* vs *B*).

Comment: Thank you, I had not realize that in some context it may be appropiate to make this  distinction.